# Поиск в SQLite если там хранятся идентификаторы на строковые ресурсы

Tags: android, sqlite

В базе данных SQLite храняться  идентификаторы на строковые ресурсы. Вопрос: как реализовать выборку текста? Если бы там были сами строки, то все понятно при помощи оператора LIKE '%р%' и все записи с буквой 'р' найдут, но как быть с ресурсами? Как можно решить эту задачу?

Comment: Правильно: не хранить в базе идентификаторы строковых ресурсов. никогда.

Comment: А как тогда сделать приложение многоязычным?

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/locale.php

Comment: Так правильно а я о чем, в ресурсах хранятся строки на разных языках. Можно конечно сразу записать в бд строки в зависимости от локали, но если я потом поменяю локаль, то все строки поменяються а те что с бд остануться прежними, поэтому там храню идентификаторы на строковые ресурсы, таким образо и из бд отображается текст на нужно языке.

Comment: Если вы удалите R.class, он пересоздастся, там будут другие идентификаторы почти наверное. У вас неверная посылка по задаче, и решение одноразовое. Задайте вопрос по изначальной задаче.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос таким образом: Получаю курсор со всеми записями из бд, потом в цыкле прохожу по курсору получая id_ресурса и проверяю
    `if(getResources().getString(id_ресурса).contains("нужная подстрока")){...}`